# Most optimal key combinations for summoner spell tracking

Tags: league-of-legends

After watching worlds 2019, I've noticed DoinB tracking summoner spells in chat and I'd like to attempt it in my own games.
Example:

> [07:00] DoinB(Sion): 1030mid 1040jg 1200ad
>   [07:01] DoinB(Sion): 1030mid 1040jg 1200ad
>   [08:52] DoinB(Sion): 1030mid 1040jg 1200ad 1340sp 1440top tp
>   [08:52] DoinB(Sion): 1030mid 1040jg 1200ad 1340sp 1440top tp
>   [10:20] DoinB(Sion): 1200ad 1340sp 1440top tp
>   [10:21] DoinB(Sion): 1200ad 1340sp 1440top tp
>   [11:16] DoinB(Sion): 1200ad 1340sp 1440top tp 1600mid
>   [11:17] DoinB(Sion): 1200ad 1340sp 1440top tp 1600mid
>   [11:48] DoinB(Sion): 1200ad 1340sp 1440top tp 1600mid
>   [11:49] DoinB(Sion): 1200ad 1340sp 1440top tp 1600mid
>   [12:25] DoinB(Sion): 1340sp 1440top tp 1600mid
>   [12:26] DoinB(Sion): 1340sp 1440top tp 1600mid

Below are my key presses at the moment

- Adding into the clipboard:

  <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> Content (eg: `1030top`) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Pasting / Repeating the clipboard in chat:

  <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Deleting from the clipboard:
  (the bolded part feels really slow and inaccurate, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> doesn't work.)

  <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Up</kbd> **<kbd>Delete</kbd>...<kbd>Delete</kbd>** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

What are the most optimal key combinations for summoner spell tracking?

Comment: People have different methods of tracking summoner spells and as long as your team can understand what you mean you don't need to spam all the cooldowns each time. Many high rank streamers track enemy spell/ult usage on a case by case basis and don't give a long list that takes time to read through. Do you want an optimal key combination for this specific format, or just any format that gets information through ?

Comment: If you want to select a part of the text, use CTRL+SHIFT+RIGHT after your UP key. In your format that should select all content until after the first space. Though it probably easier for everyone to just ping when the summoner spell as used. The client lets you ping it easily

Comment: @KaranShishoo I'd like to have this specific format, maybe with slight change to the tp timer as 1440top-tp instead of 1440top tp. I'd like to spam the list as it helps keep track of what spells are available without scrolling through the chat.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer ctrl+shift+right doesn't seem to work for me in-game, what language settings are you using for your keyboard?

Comment: German language. I havent tried that combination ingame and I have seen that it doesn't work everywhere. So it might be that its not working in league